# Inline syntax for new object of interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

it is said you can create an object using interface like this: `let o: ILookup = { id: 1, name: 'abc'}`

Whats the syntax to write this inline eg `lookups.push(ILookup = { id: 1, name: 'abc'})`?

Comment: If `lookups` has the type `Array<ILookup>`, what you're asking for is pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler is unable to infer the type based on usage you can tell the compiler that you're 100% certain you are correct and use a type assertion. (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

```
lookups.push({ id: 1, name: "abc" } as ILookup)
```

While the type assertion way works, TypeScript is clever enough most of the time to realize what you passed into `lookup.push` was a `ILookup` assuming `lookups` is of type `ILookup[]`. In this case it solves that `{ id: 1, name: "abc" }` is a perfectly valid argument to the function.